# Customize forgot_password.jsp in Liferays login hook

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-6

Use case:

- An existing Liferay user has forgotten his password.
- He clicks on the link "Forgot Password" (login hook).
- The user enters his **loginname** which is his **screenname**.
- *Now to my problem:* If a user enters a certain loginname (which i
  recognize with a regex) and clicks the button "Send new password" i want 
  to prevent the default action of this button and display a infomessage 
  instead (eg. We can't send you a new password...)

To be honest i have no idea at the moment how to approach this...

1. Maybe create an Ext plugin and override the ForgotPasswordAction class?
2. Is it possible to do it all within the forgot_password.jsp ?
3. Can i do it without writting a plugin ?

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without a plugin no, you can not do that.

1. The simplest way would be to make this would be if your password check is done in javascript or maybe with a control using ajax to use a jsp Hook and place this code in `forgot_password.jsp`

2.
 Second way would be to make a struts action hook where you override the default action `/login/forgot_password` of the update password form.For this in your liferay-hook.xml add:

```
<struts-action>
    <struts-action-path>/login/forgot_password</struts-action-path>
    <struts-action-impl>com.myproject.hook.NewPasswordPortletAction</struts-action-impl>
</struts-action>
```

Add this new class to your project an

```
public void processAction(
            StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
            PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse)
        throws Exception {
       //Custom code to handle password

        //and than call original action handler if the password entered should be saved
        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
            originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest,
            actionResponse);
    }
```

As for the Ext, you should alwayes try not to use it, since this can be done with a hook go with it.

Comment: Great answer. I'd recommend to go with 2 for the code. Maybe you need 1 for properly displaying the resulting message, but the jsp should not contain your business logic

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for helping me.